# Stop / Start call recording on Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

Is there an API that I can use to stop recording an ongoing call?

We have a feature here where you can record only pieces of a call. So you can click a button to stop recording, and then after some time you can click another button to start recording again.

How can I accomplish that on Twilio? I didn't find anything in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no direct way to start and stop recording a call, however you could manage this using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) and [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).

The idea would be that callers would [join a conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) (even if there's just two of them) which recorded their call using the [`record` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-record).

You would wrap that `<Conference>` in a `<Gather>` that was waiting for a caller to dial a particular digit which stops recording by redirecting the caller who pressed the digit to a new `<Conference>` without the record attribute set.

You will also need to redirect the other call to that conference too. When you get the webhook after the first caller pressed a digit to stop recording you can fire off a [REST API call to redirect the second caller](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) to the new non-recorded conference.

If you wrap this second `<Conference>` in a `<Gather>` too, you can reverse this process to start recording again.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**[edit]**

As a further consideration, I realised that you indicated you need a user to press a button to start or stop recording. I initially thought of this as a button on your phone, which is why I suggested using `<Gather>`. If, however, the user in control of recording is an agent in a call centre, for example, you could build an easier interface using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) to make or receive the calls.

Then, when the calls are connected into the initial conference you'd need to record both the Call SIDs.

You could then implement a button in your interface that when pressed transfers both calls from a recording conference to a non recording conference (or vice versa). Again, this would use the [REST API to redirect the calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

Comment: So basically I would have to transfer all participants to a new conference room with recording set to false, right? Ok I'll try that. Thank you! 
PS: #1 Would be nice to have this as a feature instead of having to do what you suggested. #2 Would be nice to have bulk conference methods, like ending a conference, transferring it, etc... instead of having to do it through each participant. Thanks!